# God for paladin crusader

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, paladin

I'm playing NWN2 (a videogame based on the Forgotten Realms setting during the D&D 3.5e era) on a RP server and I recently had an idea to create a paladin.

I would like to create a crusader based on Warcraft Tirion Fordring or Warhammer typical crusading and purging everything — fanatic marines.

What gods available in the game would be suitable for this kind of crusading and purging everything with fire and light?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for this site. I am guessing NWN2 stands for "Neverwinter Nights 2"? As in, the video game? If that is the case, you might want to try [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) or a video game forum.

Comment: "What god" - out of which? Are you asking about the Faerunian pantheon, the Warcraft pantheon, the Warhammer pantheon, or something completely different?

Comment: @GreedyRadish Questions about online RPGs in video games are on topic (http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/are-questions-about-roleplaying-within-a-video-game-context-on-topic). However, answering this question would require knowledge of Neverwinter Nights 2's deities, which *isn't* RPG knowledge but a specific video game mechanic, so I guess overall the question isn't answerable here.

Comment: Hm my bad then, thought that people will be familiar with NWN2 since its a forgotten realms  3,5 setting.  If it helps Kelemvor does not exist as a deity yet.

Comment: @kviiri NWN deities just so happen to be a subset (possibly the entire subset, I did not check) of the deities of the Forgotten Realms setting for D&D 3.5e, which is our field of knowledge. As long as the deity choice is just for thematic purposes (and not for taking any divinity-related powers, that might be differently implemented or differently useful in the videogame), we can answer it.

Comment: @Zachiel Cheers, I just learned this at the chat too. I think this question is answerable here, given that.

Comment: Do you want this to be a Good god, or is purge-with-hellfire an option for you?

Comment: Typical Crusading good-fantical paladin;x so Hellfire cannot be:D as far as I am aware paladins cannot even use hellfire:d

Comment: This is still probably entirely opinion-based and isn't a good fit for our site. Gods are an arbitrary choice; pick whatever you want. A burninating paladin could worship the god of the sun, or beauty, or the night, or virtually any god not actively opposing what they're doing, and any choice could make for a compelling character -- this isn't something we can answer or solve, just pick what you think works.